# Titanium - App does show from notification only once

Tags: titanium, android-notifications

My app sometimes displays multiple android notifications. When someone clicks on them, my app should show up with the content of the notifications.
I've managed to do it, but it only works for the first notification the user clicks on. If I leave the application after this (for example with the homebutton) and click then on the next notification, nothing happens.

I've created an example application to show you what I have at the moment. You can find it here: https://github.com/VanCoding/TitaniumNotificationTest

What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve what I want?

**app.js**

```
if(!Ti.App.Properties.getBool("displayedNotifications")){
    var notifications = ["Apple","Orange","Banana"];

    for(var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++){
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
            packageName:"com.company.notificationtest",
            className:"com.company.notificationtest.NotificationtestActivity",
            flags:Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED  | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        });
        intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.putExtra("name",notifications[i]);

        Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(i, Titanium.Android.createNotification({
            contentTitle: notifications[i],
            contentText : notifications[i],
            contentIntent: Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
                intent:intent,
                type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
                flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
            }),
            flags : Titanium.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT | Titanium.Android.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Titanium.Android.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
        }));
    }

    Ti.App.Properties.setBool("displayedNotifications",true);
}
```

**tiapp.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>com.company.notificationtest</id>
    <name>NotificationTest</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>not specified</publisher>
    <url></url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright>not specified</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>91e86075-373b-44e0-9416-66183390e8af</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </android>

    <modules>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.2.3.GA</sdk-version>
</ti:app>
```

Comment: do you have the same problem using the latest SDK? i.e. 3.3.0.GA?

Comment: sadly, it does also not work with SDK 3.3.0.GA... Any ideas? Does it work when you compile it?

Comment: It did run for me in 3.3.0.GA and I can reproduce the problem you stated. However, I don't think this is an inherent problem with Titanium as this gist I just made works correctly: https://gist.github.com/foolprooflabs/189af6252572a6edd5ff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
contentIntent: Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
                intent:intent,
                type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
                flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
            }),
```

to:

```
contentIntent: Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
                intent:intent,
                type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY
            }),
```

fixes it for me. Tested using 3.3.0.GA.

Comment: JESUS! That solved it!! Thank you and take my bounty :)